# How structure padding is works with respect to largest size member in C?

Tags: c, memory, structure, padding

I got some confusion while understanding structure padding concept. I have understood that structure padding increases the performance of the processor at the penalty of memory.
Here i have some structure defined

**case 1:**

```
typedef struct{
  double A; //8-byte
  char B;   //1-byte
  char C:   //1-byte
} Test1;
```

here the total size of the structure will be `16 byte` (The `largest size member` is `double`. hence compiler `aligned memory in the form of 8 byte`.)

But in these two case

**case 2:**

```
typedef struct{
  int A;     //4-byte
  double B;  //8-byte
  float C;   //4-byte
} Test2;
```

Here largest size member is `double (8 byte)`. So this will allocate  8 + 8 + 8 = 24 .

**case 3:**

```
typedef struct{
  double A;   //8-byte
  Int B;      //4-byte
  float C;    //4-byte
} Test3;
```

But here also largest size member is `double (8 byte)`. So ideally this also same as 24 byte. But when I have print the value, I am getting size `16 byte`. Why it is not behaving like `case 2` ? Any explanations ?

Comment: It's entirely implementation defined. The compiler is free to pad how it feels like. It's not the largest member per se, but instead it usually has to do with the alignment of the members.

Comment: You can look up the alignment requirements of different types on your specific system using [`alignof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/_Alignof) from C11. It may be loosely correlated with size, but you might as well examine it directly since you can.

Comment: Why would you call it "ideally" to waste 8 bytes of memory if you don't really need to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How structure padding is works with respect to largest size member in C?

Padding is fundamentally determined by the *alignment requirements* of the members, not solely by their sizes. Each complete object type has an alignment requirement, which is some number *A* such that the address of the object must always be a multiple of *A*. Alignment requirements are always powers of two.

An object’s size is always a multiple of its alignment requirement, but the alignment requirement is not always equal to the size. For example, an eight-byte `double` might have four-byte alignment in some C implementations. Alignment requirements typically arise out of hardware considerations, and a system might process eight-byte objects in four-byte chunks whenever it is loading it from memory or storing it to memory, so that hardware would not care about eight-byte alignment even for eight-byte objects. A C implementation designed for that system could make the alignment requirement for an eight-byte `double` be just four bytes.

For your examples, we will use alignment requirements of one byte for `char`, four bytes for a four-byte `float`, and eight bytes for an eight-byte `double`.

In case 1:

```
typedef struct{
  double A; //8-byte
  char B;   //1-byte
  char C:   //1-byte
} Test1;
```

The structure will always start at the required alignment boundary, because the compiler will give the structure itself an alignment requirement equal to the strictest alignment requirement of any of its members. (Greater than is also allowed by the C standard, but this is not typical in practice.) Then the `double A` occupies eight bytes. At that point, the `char B` is at an allowed place, because its alignment requirement is only one byte, so any address is allowed. And `char C` is also okay. So far, the structure is 10 bytes long. Finally, the structure needs to have an eight-byte alignment so that it can always satisfy the alignment requirement of the `double`, so the structure’s total size has to be a multiple of eight bytes. (The structure’s total size must be a multiple of its alignment requirement so that in an array of them each element starts at the required alignment.) To accomplish this, we insert six bytes of padding at the end, and the total structure size is 16 bytes.

In case 2:

```
typedef struct{
  int A;     //4-byte
  double B;  //8-byte
  float C;   //4-byte
} Test2;
```

`int A` starts at offset four. Then `double B` needs to start at a multiple of eight bytes, so four bytes of padding are inserted. Now we are up to 16 bytes: Four for `int A`, four for padding, and eight for `double B`. Then `float C` is at an okay position. It adds four bytes, and we are up to 20 bytes. The structure size needs to be a multiple of eight bytes, so we add four bytes of padding, making 24 bytes total.

In case 3:

```
typedef struct{
  double A;   //8-byte
  int B;      //4-byte [Typo fixed; was "Int".]
  float C;    //4-byte
} Test3;
```

`double A` is eight bytes, and then `int B` adds four bytes. Now we are at 12 bytes. That is okay for `float C`, because its alignment requirement is four bytes, and 12 is a multiple of four. This `float` adds four bytes to the structure, so the size is now 16 bytes. That is okay for the structure’s alignment requirement, eight bytes, because 16 is a multiple of eight. So we do not need to add any padding, and the total structure size is 16 bytes.

Here is the method that compilers commonly use to determine padding in structures:

- Each member in the structure has some size *s* and some alignment requirement *a*.
- The compiler starts with a size *S* set to zero and an alignment requirement *A* set to one (byte).
- The compiler processes each member in the structure in order:

1. Consider the member’*s* alignment requirement *a*. If *S* is not currently a multiple of *a*, then add just enough bytes to *S* so that it is a multiple of *a*. This determines where the member will go; it will go at offset *S* from the beginning of the structure (for the current value of *S*). The bytes skipped by this addition are called padding bytes.
2. Set *A* to the least common multiple<sup>1</sup> of *A* and *a*.
3. Add *s* to *S*, to set aside space for the member.

- When the above process is done for each member, consider the structure’*s* alignment requirement *A*. If *S* is not currently a multiple of *A*, then add just enough to *S* so that it is a multiple of *A*.

The size of the structure is the value of *S* when the above is done.

Additionally:

- If any member is an array, its size is the number of elements multiplied by the size of each element, and its alignment requirement is the alignment requirement of an element.
- If any member is a structure, its size and alignment requirement are calculated as above.
- If any member is a union, its alignment requirement is the least common multiple<sup>1</sup> of the alignment requirements of all its members, and its size is the size of its largest member plus just enough to make it a multiple the union’s alignment requirement.

For elementary types (`int`, `double`, et cetera), the alignment requirements are implementation-defined and are usually largely determined by the hardware. On many processors, it is faster to load and store data when it has a certain alignment (usually when its address in memory is a multiple of its size). Beyond this, the rules above follow largely from logic; they put each member where it must be to satisfy alignment requirements without using more space than necessary.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> I have worded this for a general case as using the least common multiple of alignment requirements. However, since alignment requirements are always powers of two, the least common multiple of any set of alignment requirements is the largest of them.

Answer (score 0):

> structure padding increases the performance of the processor

Not necessarily just performance - some processors *can't* even do word access to misaligned addresses.

Regarding your examples, the largest member is irrelevant. What matters is **the preferred alignment of the target system**. Which is highly CPU-specific. It's quite normal that some CPUs that can access larger data (for example 64 bits) in a single instruction also have instruction support for smaller types (for example 32 bit) and using smaller instructions than the preferred alignment does not necessarily reduce performance.

As far as the C language is concerned, a compiler may insert padding *anywhere* inside a struct except before the first member which is assumed to be aligned.

This means that discussing the behavior of your examples isn't possible or meaningful without a specific compiler and CPU in mind.

Answer (score -1):

Generally, padding is trying to read/write the specific member all at once.

For example, suppose that the CPU can only read 8 bytes at a time, and only addresses multiple of 8 are valid, which means it can access 0-7 or 8-15 etc.

```c
typedef struct{
  int A;     //4-byte
  double B;  //8-byte
  float C;   //4-byte
} Test2;
```

Without padding, it will take two times to access B since B is 4-11, it first read 0-7, then 7-15. So it adds padding before B so that B starts at 7.

```c
typedef struct{
  double A;   //8-byte
  Int B;      //4-byte
  float C;    //4-byte
} Test3;
```

This is different since all members can be accessed at one time. So padding is not needed.

Note that the alignment rule is:

1. For each member of the structure, the offset of the first member is 0, and the current offset of the following members must be an integer multiple of *the current member type*, not the largest member type.
2. After all the data members in the structure are aligned in their respective memory, the structure itself needs to be aligned once to ensure that the memory occupied by the entire structure is the smallest integer multiple of the largest data member in the structure

> https://www.codetd.com/en/article/12761430